# Add require-js to child theme at theme level

Tags: magento2, theme, requirejs

I want to add bootstrap javascript to my child theme.

I have created `app/design/frontend/<Vendor>/<theme>/requirejs-config.js`

In that file I have placed:

```
var require = {
    shim : {
        "bootstrap" : { "deps" :['jquery'] }
    },
    paths: {
        "bootstrap" :  "//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min"  
    }
};
```

This doesn't seem to do anything.  How do I add scripts properly in a child theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use bootstrap you have use data attribute mage-init for example:

```
    <div class="your-bootstrap" data-mage-init='{"bootstrap": {}}'>
         Now you can use Bootstrap here
    </div>
```

For more information how to init scripts take a look at this article http://alanstorm.com/magento_2_javascript_init_scripts/

Comment: Does this work inside the cms pages?  If I wrap a require wrapper around some script it works but the data attribute on a div isn't working.